# Jquery trigger a link created with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I use Jquery to add items to the page, those items include links. To address these new elements, I use $(container).on... etc. But how can I trigger a link that was created after the dom was built. In other words I want to programatically "click" an element created on the fly. what format should I use

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});

$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: You could also just use `$('#foo').click();`, which looks cleaner.

Comment: That's interesting. I'd already tried that without success, but I am trying to trigger from within the success function of an ajax call. If I try it outside of that function, it seems to work

Comment: Could you post the section of the code where you are trying to trigger the click event in the ajax func ?